# dropdown navigation menu malfunction

Tags: html, menu, navigation, dropdown

[updated issue!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPZei.png) I would like my navigation bar to have a drop down effect when hovering over it. I have tried the different methods suggested and my list was hidden behind my section following. So after changing it incorrectly so many time, I have now gotten confused. This is how it is currently. Now the dropdown list is stuck on display. I just want the list to show when hovering. Also the search box is supposed to be on the same line as the nav links but it has now moved below. I can figure out how to fix that if someone can help me with the drop down menu, please.

```css
.navbar {
   background: linear-gradient(#9E0A0C,#EBEBEB);
   padding: 10px;
   border-top: solid 1px #000000;
   
     }
  
  .navbar a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1.5vw;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding: 3px 5px;
   margin: auto;
   display: inline;
   
   }
  
  .navbar ul {
   
   padding: 0;
   margin-top: 0;
   width: auto;
   
  }
.navbar ul:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

  .navbar li{
   border-left: solid 2px #000000;
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline;
   width: 800px;
   padding: 0;
   /*position: relative;*/
   
  }
/*li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 94px;
    text-decoration: none;
}*/
  
  .navbar a:active {
            background-color: #000000;
         }
  
  .navbar a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
   font-size: 1.5vw;
}
  
  li:first-child {
   border-left: none;
   }
  
  .dropdown {
   display: none;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
         }
   
 .list {
   display:none;
   /*opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;*/
   z-index: 100;
         min-width: 50px;
   max-width: 350px;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #e7e7e7;
   background: #050243;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 100%;
   /*transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;*/
         }
          
    .list a {
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 1.25vw;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
   background: #dddddd;
   column-count: 2;
   }

   .list a:hover {
   background-color: #EEEEEE;
   font-size: 1.25vw;
      }

    .dropdown:hover, .list {
   display: block;
  /*position: absolute;
  left: 0;*/
   }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="../our_lodge.html" class="dropbtn">Our Lodge</a>
        <div class="list"> <a href="https://www.elks.org/lodges/lodgenews.cfm?LodgeNumber=151">NEWS</a> <a href="../facilities.html">FACILITIES</a> <a href="../officers.html">OFFICERS</a> <a href="https://www.elks.org/lodges/GuestBook.cfm?LodgeNumber=151">GUEST BOOK</a> </div>
         </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="../events.html" class="dropbtn">Events</a>
        <div class="list"> <a href="../assests/April2018_Calendar.pdf">CALENDAR</a> <a href="../assests/0151_BINGOSCHEDULE-April2018.pdf">BINGO</a> </div>
         </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="../contact.html" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
      <div class="list"> <a href="../who_are_we.html">WHO ARE WE?</a> </div>
        <div class="list"> <a href="../become_an_elk.html">BECOME AN ELK</a> </div>
         </li>
      
       </ul><form action="search.html">
        <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
         </form>
     </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. within your css the line `.dropdown:hover, .list {` should be `.dropdown:hover .list {` without the comma
2. put your form into an `<li>` element within the `<ul>`. the `float: right` should be assigned to the form not the input

html:

```
    ...
        </li> 
        <li>
          <form class="navbar-search" action="search.html">
            <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </nav>
```

css:

```
.navbar-search {
  float: right;
}
```

---

update:

3. I don't know why you would like to have a `column-count`. is this on purpose?
4. in the last `<li>`element are two divs -> one overlays the other
5. please do you self a favour and reduce the amount of whitspaces as well as putting one html element per line and use comments (html AND css)! this makes debugging a whole lot easier and you will still understand what you did yesterday.

---

update 2:

```css
.navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(#9E0A0C, #EBEBEB);
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px #000000;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.navbar li {
  border-left: solid 2px #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

/*li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 94px;
  text-decoration: none;
}*/
.navbar a:active {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
  min-width: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #e7e7e7;
  background: #050243;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.list a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background: #dddddd;
}

.list a:hover {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}

.dropdown:hover .list {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-search {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>

    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a href="../our_lodge.html" class="dropbtn">Our Lodge</a>
    <div class="list"> 
      <a href="https://www.elks.org/lodges/lodgenews.cfm?LodgeNumber=151">NEWS</a>
      <a href="../facilities.html">FACILITIES</a> 
      <a href="../officers.html">OFFICERS</a> 
      <a href="https://www.elks.org/lodges/GuestBook.cfm?LodgeNumber=151">GUEST BOOK</a> 
    </div>
   </li>

   <li class="dropdown"><a href="../events.html" class="dropbtn">Events</a>
     <div class="list"> 
       <a href="../assests/April2018_Calendar.pdf">CALENDAR</a> 
       <a href="../assests/0151_BINGOSCHEDULE-April2018.pdf">BINGO</a> 
     </div>
   </li>

   <li class="dropdown"><a href="../contact.html" class="dropbtn">Contact Us</a>
     <div class="list"> 
       <a href="../who_are_we.html">WHO ARE WE?</a> 
       <a href="../become_an_elk.html">BECOME AN ELK</a> 
     </div>
   </li>

<li>
  <form class="navbar-search"action="search.html">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  </form>
</li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you @noob! That corrected majority of the issue but the dropdown is still hidden behind the next section. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: what do you mean with "behind the next section". testing on firefox it does look okayish.

Comment: I removed the column-count and corrected the double div. Originally each element was its own line but the spaces were closed in as I copied from one program (dreamweaver) to notepad. I made it so the dropdowns are no longer hidden but now they stretch out the nav bar.-  I added a link in my original question to show you how the nav bar is currently working. (I didn't know how else to include a picture)

Comment: sorry, I can't reproduce the behaviour show in your image - tried Edge, Firefox and Chrome 
I updated my answer with "my" code. hope you will find a solution